# find columns containing all nan after grouping pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

in a dataframe `df` how can I find the columns that contains all nan after grouping the rows?

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
     a    b  group
0  NaN  NaN  a
1  0.0  NaN  a
2  2.0  NaN  a
3  1.0  7.0  b
4  1.0  3.0  b
5  7.0  4.0  b
6  2.0  6.0  c
7  9.0  6.0  c
8  3.0  0.0  c
9  9.0  0.0  c
```

in this case the desired output should be 
group: a - columns: b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by grouping column first, then find all `NaN`s by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html).

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html). Last reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and create new `DataFrame` with all groups and columns names:

```
print (df.set_index('group').isnull().groupby('group').all())
           a      b
group              
a      False   True
b      False  False
c      False  False
```

---

```
a = df.set_index('group').isnull().groupby('group').all().stack()

b = pd.DataFrame(a[a].index.values.tolist(), columns=['group','cols'])
print (b)
  group cols
0     a    b
```

Comment: I try create new `df` with output.

Answer (score 0):

try this ?

```
df.groupby('group').sum().unstack()[df.groupby('group').sum().unstack().isnull()].reset_index()

  level_0 group   0
0       b     a NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ? i.e get the group name and the value column that as full Nan values

```
vals = [(i['group'].iloc[0],i.columns[i.isnull().all()].tolist()) for _,i in df.groupby('group')]
```

Output:

```
[('a', ['b']), ('b', []), ('c', [])]
```